# Как поведет себя crossbar.io в случае потери связи у звонящего?

Tags: wamp

Клиент:

1. вызвал процедуру,
2. отвалился до ответа процедуры и/или во время распределённого ответа,
3. снова законнектился (по факту новая сессия).

Как поведет себя crossbar.io?

1. вычислит клиента по `authid` - и отдаст ответ/продолжит отдавать ответы,
2. выкинет ошибку, что, мол, сессия отвалилась,
3. тихо умолчит об этом.